# Running PyQt QApplication from Django under mod_wsgi

Tags: django, pyqt, pyqt4, mod-wsgi, pyside

I'm trying to implement a screenshot renderer from within a Django application using PyQt/PySide in which I will feed a string of HTML directly to a QWebPage and render the mainFrame. I've tested and was able to get this to work as a standalone python script (below).

However, the Django/Apache/mod_wsgi server hangs and won't respond when attempting to call `QApplication([])`. (Note: I've tried both PyQt and PySide and get the same results with either).

I'm suspect of something being the problem with wsgi being unable to start up the Qt Application.

Here is, more or less, the extent of the wsgi setup:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess site processes=2 threads=4 maximum-requests=10 inactivity-timeout=0.5
WSGIProcessGroup site
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /etc/apache2/site.wsgi
```

Here's the view file in the Django application:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, division

import sys

from PySide import QtWebKit
from PySide.QtNetwork import (
    QNetworkRequest, QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkCookieJar,
    QNetworkDiskCache, QNetworkProxy, QNetworkCookie)
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide.QtCore import (
    QSize, QByteArray, QUrl, QDateTime, QtCriticalMsg, QtDebugMsg, QtFatalMsg,
    QtWarningMsg, qInstallMsgHandler)
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QImage, QPainter, QPrinter


from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from app.views.common import *

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Renderer(QtWebKit.QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, html):
        log.debug('getting application')
        """
            This is where the application hangs!!!!
        """
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        log.debug('app %s', self.app)
        super(QtWebKit.QWebPage, self).__init__()

        self.url = QUrl(url)

        self.mainFrame().setHtml(html)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.render)
        self.app.exec_()

    def render(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


class StaticImageView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        view_func, args, kwargs = resolve(request.GET.get('path'))
        html = view_func(self.request, *args, **kwargs)
        r = Renderer(html)
        size = QSize(1200, 800)
        r.setViewportSize(size)
        image = QImage(size, QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        painter = QPainter(image)
        r.frame.render(painter)
        painter.end()
        image.save('/tmp/foo.png')
        return render(request, 'pages/success.html', {})
```

And the following is the script that works when called directly. https://gist.github.com/paularmstrong/7472484

So, my question is: Why does `QApplication([])` hang when called during an HTTP request through mod_wsgi in Django?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

but I suspect the problem is that since the web application runs as special Apache user, without inheriting anything from your personal user environment, it knows nothing about how to interact with your UI session.

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction. Instead of the request hanging and timing out, I get a 500 error with the following in the apache log: `mod_wsgi: cannot connect to X server`. What do you mean by "interact with your UI session"? This is a headless server environment and doesn't have a true GUI. Do I need to have QApplication run as a specific user? How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: To communicate with the X server, there is generally an environment variable present which directs an application to which server it should talk to. There could also be authorisation information. These will not exist.